# Running ASP.NET and SQL Server on WD my cloud ex2

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, windows-server, nas

I just bought a WD my cloud ex2.
The reason I bought this over the white original my cloud is that this machine can produce a public IP for FTP transfer, becoming a true cloud based storage. But i also want to free myself from the chains of expensive web-hosting and it makes me feel even more pathetic because I have a storage device and I'm still buying storage for my websites. I build asp.net websites using WebMatrix, and have a SQL Server Database. Can my storage device run ASP.NET? I don't know much about Windows Server, but does that have to be installed in the myCloud? Would there be any way to do so?
Thank you.

Comment: Cloud storage=not on your premises. You shouldn't put too much faith in marketing speak.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Not an MS box.  But you can use MySQL and recode your asp.net to php.  Another great choice would be to get a free (for 1 year) Amazon Web Services EC2 instance.  You can run a small MS Server there and keep your stuff in ASP.net